# Versioning style for open source CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, github

I've developed my own CMS - I don't claim it's the best or even good, I only wanted to face problems creating such system might bring.
Currently I've got problem with designing some reasonable versioning system for my CMS.

What I've got for now:

1. Project is being hosted on GitHub (actually not yet),
2. There are two branches:

   - devel for current changes
   - main for stable changes form devel

My first idea was to create update system using GitHub API - user is comparing his local latest commit sha with sha at project's page - if not up to date download files. This solution had one big downside - API's requests limits, one user would be able to shut down whole 'update server' because of too many requests per minute.
Instead of this I'll use 'GitHub Pages' to store project page and upate changsets generated locally by myself (modified git diff output in JSON format with additional information). In this idea I don't use commits to check update status but version number.
Lets say my GitHub page looks like this:

```
index.html
/changsets
+--0.0.1.json
+--0.0.2.json
...
+--1.0.0.json
```

Every JSON file in changsets dir will hold list of files changed since version of it's name - if 1.0.0 is current version file 1.0.0.json will contain an empty array.
What should be the format of version number? Three integers might not look very good when it's 1.0.55 or 1.55.21. When should I even push changes from devel to master branch? I'm not such experienced as Joomla / Drupal team so I don't have any schedule or list of features to be done to release version X (most of updates will be bugfixes for sure).
If version will change too often I'll need to generate dozens of JSON files what will waste both time and resources. Maybe I should have some deadline of six months when no changsets will be generated?
I know I should have some webserver with REST API to handle it but I want my project to be hosted on GitHub entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the version scheme you could use [Semantic Versioning](http://www.semver.org)

Checking for updates each time a page is viewed is unrealistic and can actually be a threat if a high-profile site is using your script. Instead, you could add a page or option to the admin panel to have the administrator check for updates.

Comment: Very useful specification with precise tips / requirements. Thank you!  Any ideas about storing chngsets?

Comment: You could do that in the repository or you could also utilize another service, such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), and have a specific page where the administrator can check for updates manually (to prevent overloading the update server).

Comment: I just wanted to wait a little if someone else will post something interesting too :)